# Semantic UI multi-select dropdown prevent element selection

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I am having a dropdown with 4 elements such as

```
'All', 'Fi', 'Cu', 'Common'.
```

Here, user has to be allowed to select `'All'` only when there is no element in it. If it has at least one element say `'Cu'` in it &  if user is selecting `'All'` then the selection has to be prevented and `'All'` will be removed from the dropdown.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css"></script>

<div style="padding:10px;width:200px;">
    <select id="du_select" class="ui fluid dropdown" name="du_graph_types" multiple="">
        <option value="">Select DU</option>
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="copper">Copper</option>
        <option value="fiber">Fiber</option>
        <option value="common">Common</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#du_select').dropdown({
        onChange: function(value, text, $selectedItem) {
            // custom action
            if (value.length > 1 && value.includes('all')) {
                const index = value.indexOf('all');
                if (index > -1) {
                    value.splice(index, 1);
                }
                console.log('sel_items : ' + value)
                $('#du_select').dropdown('clear').dropdown('set selected',value)
                alert('Before selecting "All", clear the existing DU type')
            }

        }
    });

</script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2y0ojqg5/1/)

But, while doing so, the elements are getting removed from the dropdown itself.

What is the mistake I'm making here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are using the wrong parameters in your logic. This solution should work.. simply change your onChange params.

The dropdown onChange gives you:
1) array of all options that have been selected
2) currently selected value

So you want to do this:

```
$('#du_select').dropdown({
        onChange: function(selected, value) {
    console.log(value)
    console.log(selected)
            // custom action
            if (selected.length > 1 && selected.includes('all')) {
                const index = selected.indexOf('all');
                if (index > -1) {
                    selected.splice(index, 1);
                }
                console.log('sel_items : ' + selected)
                $('#du_select').dropdown('clear').dropdown('set selected',value)
                //$('#du_select').;
                alert('Before selecting "All", clear the existing DU type')
            }

        }
    });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yumxj47v/

Comment: Here `$('#du_select').dropdown('clear').dropdown('set selected',value)` is making the `onChange` function to be called multiple times.

Comment: Sure, but that is again, your own code and error. This answer solved your question of: "the elements are getting removed from the dropdown itself. What is the mistake I'm making here ?", which is your incorrect parameter

Comment: function being called multiple times is not the cause of why the items were getting removed from the dropdown, when you make a selection.

Answer (score 0):

get number of  options in the list by using **$('#input1 option').length;** then apply your conditions according to your logic. There you will get 5 for your given code. Let me knw for more detials

Answer (score 0):

Upon exploring the Semantic-UI documentation, I found a way to solve it, by providing the [custom select action](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#specifying-select-action).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#du_select').dropdown({
        action: function(text, value) {
            // nothing built in occurs
            existing_elems = $(this).dropdown("get value")
            //console.log(value)
            if (existing_elems.includes('all')) {
                alert('No options allowed to add, while "All" is already selected')
            } else if (existing_elems.length > 0 && value == 'all') {
                alert('Before selecting "All", clear the existing DU type')
            } else {
                $(this).dropdown('set selected',value)
            }
            $(this).dropdown('hide')
        }
    });

</script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srLhdj6m/)

Comment: you were just using the wrong parameters in your logic. check my answer, it simply changes your param you are using

Comment: also, your question was about what you were doing wrong :)